# How to check JRE Version before application installed, Mac Installer

Tags: macos, installation

Hi I want to check JRE version before my application is installed in Mac OS. If JRE version is not greater than 1.5 then I want to show a dialogbox to the user to install JRE afer and installation should exit. Othewise Installation should work fine. How to achieve this functionality.
Whether I have to write any script and where to execute the script or any thing else that I have to do.

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you have to write a pre-installation script. I know how to write java script and that java script will return either true or false. I am not sure how to write shell script for that.

Thanks
Deepak